# Windows Forms C# Combo Box List Box

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

```
private void cmbUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (cmbUsers.SelectedText == "<All Users>")
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        else if (cmbUsers.SelectedText == "dbo")
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        else if (cmbUsers.SelectedText == "INFORMATION_SCHEMA")
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        else if (cmbUsers.SelectedText == "sys")
        {
            //do stuff
        }
}
```

I have a form on which there is a combo box and a list box.

When user select  from combo box list all list box records should be shown . But when user select dbo only dbo.abc records should be shown in list box. When user select INFORMATION_SCHEMA records with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.abc should be shown. My English is not great . I hope you all understand my question.

Please help me.

Comment: use combobox text changed event

Comment: unfortunately no, we can't understand because there's no question...have you even written one single line of code? or you're asking for a tutorial?

Comment: yes.. And write do stuff codes..

Comment: @Astro now  what i want is i dont want to show all records form the list box if the user has select dbo

Comment: show us your code about the listbox datas please

Comment: @Benji_9989 i have fill list box from property window collection. I am new to winforms.

Comment: you should see with the Ronan Lamour answer, trying with dictionnary. Cause with listbox you can't set visibility=false to some items easily. You'll have to define which items are in the listbox after each combobox_selectedIndexChanged event

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty ways to resolve something like this.

My first attempt should be to create a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and add all keys to Combobox. They keys are your "dbo.abc" and so on and the values are corresponding records.
On Combobox index changed event, you then clear your listbox and add all items from the corresponding list to it.

For all items, you can add a "all list" item in combobox. Then, on your test to see if the key exists in dictionary, if it doesn't exists, you can `foreach` on `yourDictionary.Values` and add them all to your listbox.

That's probably the way I'll do it. But there are plenty others and maybe you should start to improve your C# language before asking trivial questions like this :)

Edit on your example (supposing your listbox is cmbList) :

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _items;

private void cmbUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cmbText = cmbUsers.SelectedText;
    cmbList.Items.Clear();

    if (_items.ContainsKey(cmbText)
    {
        cmbList.Items.AddRange(_items[cmbList]);           
    }
    else // default : show all items
    {
        foreach (var val in _items.Values)
        {
            cmbList.Items.AddRange(val);
        } 
    }        
}
```

Comment: i am new to winforms. can u further explain how to do this

Comment: I think you can just change cmbList to your listBox name and then copy paste my code :)

Comment: no i think u have not understand my question

Comment: i will upload a pic after 10 reputation then u will be able to see what exactly i want to do